# Visual Studio 2015 “Apply Code Changes” is disabled

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio 2015, “Apply Code Changes” is always disabled. I've seen MANY posts regarding this, but I haven't found a solution.

Here are some details:

- Project > Properties > Linker > General > Enable Incremental Linking is "Yes (/INCREMENTAL)".
- Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Debug Information Format is "Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI).
- Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Edit and Continue has a checkmark, as do Enable Native Edit and Continue, Apply changes on continue, Warn about stale code, and Allow precomiling are all checked.
- Project > Properties > General > Platform Toolset is set to "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)".
- I deleted my project's *.ilk file.

This was working with this project. I think it stopped working when I changed to the VS 2015 IDE (as noted above, I still compile it using the 2010 compiler).

Thanks!

Comment: New debugger / old compiler, that is not a happy mix.  Nothing I can check, try Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Native Compatibility Mode" option.

Comment: That gets me really close, Hans. The command is no longer disabled, bit if I compile (Alt+F10) a message displaying "Edits were made that can not be compiled" is displayed (even if the edit is simple, like changing "x=1" to "x = 2"). Maybe this is a problem caused by a new IDE and an older compiler, but it does seem to be well support with the IDE's options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default debugger does not support Edit and Continue with v100 toolset.

Here's a workaround to get Native ENC working with older toolsets (eg. v100):

1. Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ (or corresponding path for a custom VS2010 install) to your VS environment PATH variable. You can add this through:

   - Global environment variables: Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables…  and Edit “Path”> New to add. -or-
   - Alternatively, you can open up a Developer Command Prompt for VS2015, call
     `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\` and call devenv.
2. In Debug > Options, ensure “Use Native Compatibility Mode” and “Enable Native Edit and Continue” are enabled.
3. In your project properties, ensure the C/C++ > General > Debug Information Format is “Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI)”, among other settings (see my [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/01/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015-update-3/) for reference).

Comment: Thanks Ramkumar. I bit the bullet and moved the project to use the 2015 compiler (which required compiling several third party libraries), so I can't say if your solution will work. It looks detailed enough... I'm mark it as the answer.

Comment: I think I found the answer why am I am not able to use it on https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/22/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015/ : **Edit and Continue for x64 requires the v140 toolset**: Supporting x64 EnC required significant updates to the compiler so it is not possible with prior versions of the compiler. — Altough I am using VS2017, the Platform Toolset is Visual Studio 2013 (v120)